# MarkLogic Xquery finding all timestamps within 1 minute of eachother

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Sorry for this rather specific use case.

I have a sequence of documents that all have a timestamp field:

```
2021-12-15T03:06:04Z
2021-12-15T03:06:14Z
2021-12-15T03:06:24Z
2021-12-15T03:06:34Z
2021-12-15T03:06:44Z
2021-12-15T03:07:04Z
2021-12-15T03:17:04Z
```

My aim is to identify which documents are all within 1 minute of eachother, and delete all documents except one of those (so we only have 1 document per any 60 second interval). Which document is kept is not important.

Is there any dateTime functions or xfunct functions I could leverage to tackle this elegantly? A big caveat of the data is that all timestamps are random, there are no patterns to the timestamps coming back we could build off of. There is also around 1k documents that this needs to be run on every 3 hours, so performance is also an issue.

Thank you in advance to anyone who replies.

Comment: What should happen if the range of dense timestamps is longer than a minute? If you have a document cluster that runs from 00:00:00 to 00:02:05, is there a preferred solution between (00:00:00; 00:01:02; 00:02:05) and (00:00:29; 00:01:31)?

Comment: @benW I think the prefeered solution would be the first option here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group them by the dateTime formatted with minute precision, use that as the key for a map, and just perform a put with those values. At the end, there will only be one entry per minute.

```
let $dates := ("2021-12-15T03:06:04Z",
"2021-12-15T03:06:14Z",
"2021-12-15T03:06:24Z",
"2021-12-15T03:06:34Z",
"2021-12-15T03:06:44Z",
"2021-12-15T03:07:04Z",
"2021-12-15T03:17:04Z")!xs:dateTime(.)

let $dates-by-minute := map:map()
let $_group :=
  for $date in $dates
  let $key := fn:format-dateTime($date, "[Y01]/[M01]/[D01] [H01]:[m01]")
  return map:put($dates-by-minute, $key, $date)

return
  map:keys($dates-by-minute) ! map:get($dates-by-minute, .)
```

Comment: If the document cluster spans across a minute boundary, like 00:00:45 to 00:01:15, this would still allow two documents to survive within 60 seconds of each other.

Comment: Sure, and you could extend that further and maybe look to round the remaining seconds or then use the reduced items and further calculate differences. Iterate through them and if (n - n+1) is less than 60, consolidate.

Comment: @MadsHansen we had a requirement change to where instead of every minute being the interval we can look every 15 minutes and save one document from every 15 minutes. How would your code sample change?

Comment: I would adjust the key by changing the format to exclude minute, then append a value that is minute divided by 15: `let $key := fn:format-dateTime($date, "[Y01]/[M01]/[D01] [H01]:") || number(fn:format-dateTime($date, "[m01]")) idiv 15`